# Need to display two different list one Wingrid

Tags: infragistics

Need to display two different list of bellow displayed type on one Wingrid in one band . Grouping by category and showing only distinct list.

Note: 2 types have more fields that might be different but have to display only common fields

Comment: I agree that the question isn't clear.  If you have a common base class that contains the shared properties, could you bind to a single list?

Answer (score 0):

Have both types of items in a single bindable list and populate columns (UltraGridColumn) of grid programmatically (key of column - property name) for which (common) properties you need.